# SELECT query with LIKE fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

I'm using a SQL SELECT query to bring back all rows from a specific date.

The column I'm using is called `TimeStamp` (datetime)

(An example of data from this column = `01/02/2018 07:55:55`)

What I would like is to return all rows from a specific date eg `24/06/2019`

I have tried

```
SELECT top 20 TimeStamp
from Report
where TimeStamp = '02/01/2018 07:55:55'
```

which returns one row (which is correct as there is only one row containing this data)

If I then try

```
SELECT top 20 TimeStamp
from Report
where TimeStamp LIKE '02/01/2018%'
```

I get no results, I have also tried escaping the forward slashes

```
SELECT top 20 TimeStamp
from Report
where TimeStamp = '02\/01\/2018%'
```

Comment: what SQL are you using?

Comment: Its SQL server 2008 and the datatype of the TimeStamp column comes back as datetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most databases support a string function called `left()`.  If I assume that your "timestamp" is a string, then:

```
where left(timestamp, 10) = '01/02/2018'
```

However, it should be stored as a date or date/time.  If so, then you can do:

```
where timestamp >= '2018-02-01' and
      timestamp < '2018-02-02'
```

Note the use of standard formatted dates (YYYY-MM-DD).  That is the way most databases implement date literals.

In SQL Server, you can also use:

```
where convert(date, timestamp) = '2018-02-01'
```

Both this and the previous version will use an index on `timestamp`, so both are reasonable solutions.

Comment: in the second example you can use between

Comment: Thankyou for the very quik answer and for covering both datatypes of the column, the datatype was indeed stored as date/time and your example worked perfectly.

Comment: @EladL. . . . No.  `between` includes both endpoints, and you don't want the second endpoint.  Plus, you shouldn't use `between` with date/time values.  Read this:  https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.

Comment: I'd also be careful with `yyyy-mm-dd` and prefer `yyyymmdd`. The reason? Try `SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2018-02-01');` under `SET LANGUAGE French -- or polski or german or ...`

Comment: Thankyou, using convert worked and seemed quicker in returning the rows.

Comment: @Retroisbest Open-ended range is better than converting the column. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/1186

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
SELECT TimeStamp FROM report where convert(Date, TimeStamp) = '2019-06-24'
```

Comment: This "works" but it is not the best approach; please read https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/1186

Answer (score -1):

or `select timestamp from report where timestamp between '2019-06-24' and '2019-06-25'`. This will get you everything between 2019-06-24 00:00:00 and 2019-06-25 00:00:00 thus all records with date 2019-06-24

Comment: This is a [terrible idea](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), as it might include rows from June 25th.

Comment: depends what he wants. If he wants midnight records included this is the way to go. it does not return random 25-06-2019 rows only with timestamp 00:00:00

Comment: Midnight rows from the next day? Then the OP shouldn't *also* want midnight rows from the current day. And they wouldn't have been trying with `LIKE`, because `'06/25/2019 00:00:00` is absolutely not like `'06/24/2019%'`.

Comment: using [between](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is a bad idea in general

Answer (score -1):

Convert timestamp value to date.

```
SELECT TimeStamp 
FROM report 
WHERE CAST(TimeStamp AS DATE) = '2019-06-24'
```